# scala:console is worse than Scala's own REPL?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-plugin

Using [`maven-scala-plugin`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/) I can run Scala console with all dependencies as:

```
mvn scala:console
```

However, what I get is much more **poor REPL** than Scala's own one (the one you get when run `scala` without arguments). E.g. it misses **auto-completion** and **history**, **arrow keys** just print their code (instead of moving cursor), etc.

Is it known issue or just a misconfiguration in my setup? If first, what are alternatives to `scala:console` (i.e. REPL with all dependencies and compiled code)?

---

Plugin configuration in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @SeanVieira: thanks, just moved solution to answers. Will mark it as accepted in 2 days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the version org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.x of the plugin is deprecated/dead (due to EOL of scala-tools.org, maven3 convention,...).

Try

```
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
```

(Note : I'm the author of both plugins).

Answer (score 3):

It's interesting how asking questions on SO makes you think in another direction and find answers yourself. It turns out I missed error message on REPL start:

> Failed to created JLineReader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/jline/console/completer/Completer
>   Falling back to SimpleReader.

Which quickly leads to [solution](http://www.hashcode.eti.br/?p=475) - one just needs to add JLine to dependency list:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0-1</version>
</dependency>
```